# Como deixar código no formato da linguagem dentro do word

Tags: c, microsoft-word, syntax-highlight

Atualmente tenho um código na linguagem C. Preciso apresentar esse código em um trabalho através de PDF ou .doc. Porém formatar um código no Microsoft Word para deixá-lo igual na IDE é muito trabalhoso.

Existe alguma ferramenta que eu consiga exportar o código da IDE direto para o Word?

Comment: Utilizando o Internet Explorer no site abaixo consegue uma boa formatação, mas não conheço nenhuma ferramenta automática. http://www.planetb.ca/syntax-highlight-word

Comment: Quando você copia da IDE e cola no MS Word não preserva a formatação? Não sei que IDE você utiliza, mas já fiz isso com código C# no Visual Studio, ele preservava a formatação ao colar em algum processador de texto.

Comment: Qual é o IDE que está a utilizar?

Comment: Utilizo o Devc++. Pelo menos no salvar como não tem nenhuma opção

Answer (score 4):

Tem um caminho interessante, usando ferramentas inusitadas:

A linguagem Python segue um dos principios da filosofia do Unix em que é melhor ter várias ferramentas pequenas que façam uma coisa e bem.

Então, compartilhado entre os vários interpretadores interativos, IDEs, engines de template, há um pacote no Python que faz a formatação de cores de código fonte de linguagens, o pacote [pygments](http://pygments.org/). E o interessante é que tanto ele aceita várias linguagens de entrada - mais de 300, e, claro **c** inclusive, como pode ser usado direto como uma ferramenta de linha de comando, sem precisar de um programa em Python para ser usado. Ele vários formatos de saída, com a formatação em cores. Aqui testei rapidamente: ele não tem saída em `.docx`, mas tem saída em `.rtf` que o Word deve ler com as cores e tabulações no lugar, sem problemas. (Pode também criar arquivos `png` ou outros com imagens dos programas).

## Windows

Como fazer se vocẽ não tem um ambiente Python? Bom, crie um - todo o runtime do Python é bem leve e rápido de instalar - vá no site http://python.org e baixe a última versão (nesse momento, a 3.6, em alguns meses a 3.7). Creio que durante a instalação há uma opção para "garantir que o Python esteja no Path" - habilite essa opção.

Normalmente o Python fica instalado em `C:\Python36\bin\Python` - você não vai precisar digitar o diretório nos próximos comandos se adicionou o Python ao seu Path. Tente digitar  `python<enter>` no cmd, e veja se vai dentro do Python (o prompt fica `>>>`), ou se precisa digitar o diretório e qual diretório. Quando funcionar, saia digitando `ctrl + Z` e `<enter>`.

Agora é só instalar o Pygments - para isso, digite no prompt do cmd:
`python -m pip install pygments`

Isso vai instalar o pygments, que tanto pode ser usado como uma biblioteca Python, como disponibiliza uma ferramenta de linha de comando para criar a saída colorida em vários formatos (terminal ANSI, .rtf, .html, etc...) do código fonte colorido.

Vá com o comando `cd` até a pasta onde está seu código em C e digite algo como:  `c:\python36\scripts\pygmentize -o arquivo.rtf arquivo.c`  - isso deve criar um novo arquivo do tipo "rtf" (que é um formato "light" de texto formatado que a Microsoft criou com o Wordpad que vinha de graça com o windows desde a década de 90. ) Se vocẽ não tiver uma mensagem de erro, deve ter o arquivo .rtf na mesma pasta, basta abri-lo com o Word e colar no seu documento final (ou usar opções de `formatar->inserir`, etc...).

Se tiver algum erro no processo vai ser relativo as pastas e caminhos da instalação no windows - é só descobrir os caminhos corretos.

## Linux, Mac OS

Em outros sistemas, o Python já vem instalado, e o pygments existe como um aplicativo do sistema - algo como `apt-get install python-pygments` ou `pip install pygments` direto no Mac, e você terá o comando `pygmentize` a disposição.